# Is possible to use a 3rd Party Controller or Mouse + Keyboard on the Windows PS4 Remote Play App?

Tags: pc, ps4, ps-remote-play

I recently found out about the official PS4 Remote Play application for Windows. Sadly, I don't have a separate DualShock 4 to use by another player from the Windows PC so I was thinking:

- Is Possible to use a 3rd Party Controller? (Xbox 360/One)
- What about previous generation DualShock? (PS2 via Adapter/PS3 via USB)
- On the other side, what about Keyboard + Mouse?

The only thing that I can do is to watch the other player that is using the DS4 directly to the console:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ViGEm supports emulation of a DualShock 4, I dug around frameworks which utilize ViGEm. As a result, I discovered two promising solutions:

- **[VDX](https://github.com/ViGEm/VDX)** is a mere demo application, but is still powerful enough to emulate a DualShock with an XInput controller (which translates to an XBOX 360 controller or an Xbox One controller). Although it says "it must be used with X360CE," you can safely disregard the X360CE part if you are already using an Xbox-compatible device.
- **[InputMapper](https://beta.inputmapper.com/)** has a more thorough control upon your input device and even maps from DualShock to DualShock, well, if you are behind a third-party dongle.

They are on the driver-layer, which means they do not require a modification on the remote play app itself. Whether it affects you positively or negatively depends on your use.

※ Since this answer falls into a "tool recommendation" answer, I declare that I am not affiliated with either ViGEm or InputMapper.